# ifelse function in data.table does not produce the right values

Tags: r

I have a very simple "ifelse" function that should include many "or" conditions and then simply assign a 1 or 0.

I tried changing the arguments.

```
dt.data[, new_variable:= ifelse(sic==2833|2834|2835|2836,1,0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2833|2834|2835|2836` is `TRUE`

so you're actually calling `dt.data[, new_variable:= ifelse(sic== TRUE,1,0)]`

Where you probably mean `dt.data[, new_variable:= ifelse(sic %in% c(2833, 2834, 2835, 2836),1,0)]`